# General transcription factors vs. DNA Binding transcription factors

Tags: molecular-biology, transcription, transcription-factor

I know that DNA binding transcription factors are trans-acting, but what about general transcription factors? 
Are they cis or trans acting?

Comment: Hi there and welcome to biology.se. For this site users are expected to do a little background reading before asking a question. What sources have you looked at that lead to this question?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_factor): *A defining feature of transcription factors is that they contain one or more DNA-binding domains (DBDs), which attach to specific sequences of DNA adjacent to the genes that they regulate.* So, there's no differentiation between *"DNA-binding transcription factors"* and *"general transcription factors"*. In order to be classified as a TF, a protein *must* be capable of directly binding DNA.

Answer (score 2):

When we say *trans* we mean that a diffusible factor, or agent is involved. So a molecule synthesized at one location, that can have a regulatory role in another location in the cell is said to be a "*trans*-acting" factor.

When we say *cis* we mean physically linked to, in such a way that the biological regulation only affects other molecules that are attached (in other words, something that is "*cis*-acting" cannot be freely diffusible).

So prokaryotic operators or promoters, and eukaryotic enhancers and promoters would be examples of *cis*-acting sequences, or elements.  All protein transcription factors, or even DNA-binding proteins, are therefore *trans*-acting.

Answer (score 1):

[General transcriptional factor complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_factor) bind to DNA at promoters of genes via DNA binding proteins such as TATA-binding protein.

It is quite clear that it is trans-acting.

Comment: I agree, all transcription factors are trans-acting. I just am not sure that I agree with you first sentence completely. Some of the proteins bind to other proteins and don't themselves have a DNA binding domain. I might be wrong in the sense that these proteins may not be canonically considered TFs, but they do exist.